# Circular relationship in DB design

Tags: sql, database

I've some doubts about my database design. I've four tables that follow the following rules:

- One form can have many questions (0..n).
- One form can have many responses (0..n).
- A question belongs to one form (1).
- A response belongs to one form (1).
- A response have many anwers to a question (Answer table) (0..n).
- An Answer belongs to an specific question of a form(1).

The design has led to a circular looking dependency graph like the following:

`Form <------------------------------- Question
   ^                                    ^
   |                                    |
   |                                    |
 Response <---------------------------- Answer`

Can anyone help me? Thanks for all.

Comment: I don't think Form can have multiple questions, and no answer can have many questions, those rules you write seems wrong to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach seems wrong. "One form can have many questions. One form can have many answer. An answer belongs to one form."

No, an answer should refer to a specific **question**. If a question belongs to a form, then the answers do belong to that form implicitly, but only indirectly, because they belong to a question.

It boils down to:

- One form can have many questions.
- One question can have many answers.

In the form of tables:

- table form (form_id, ...)
- table question (question_id, question_text, ..., form_id)
- table answer (answer_id, answer_text, ..., question_id)

**UPDATE according to latest request edit:**

So you have forms, questions and aswers as shown above. Additionally you want to store the responses. A response contains several answers and some statistics.

- table response (response_id, form_id, submit_time, ...)
- table response_answer (response_id, answer_id)

Comment: I think you wrong, you miss another table between forms and questions, and the same for questions and answers

Comment: @Sami: In my model a question belongs to only one form and an answer belongs to only one question. If you want to use the same question in multiple forms or use the same answer for multiple questions, then yes, you'd use bridge tables instead.

Comment: Yes, and I don't think those rules(what OP write) right, this not logical at all

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot to mention that the Answer table is for save information not about an specific answer to a question but to save information like the time of submit or information about the network of the respondent. So an answer to a form mantain this information and have many answers for the form's questions. Sorry for my english.

Comment: I don't completely understand. A form has questions. Thses questions have answers. And then you want to store statistics about the answers? This may be another table `answer_stat(answer_stat_id, answer_id, submit_time, ping_time, ...)`.

Comment: Yes, that's what I want, but I dont want to repeat this information for every answer. Maybe I should delete the relation between Answer and Form?

Comment: If you have a relationship between form and answer, I would suggest you delete it.

Comment: I cannot tell. If this is not information on a specific answer, but a question, then make this question_stat referring to a question and not an answer. Or if it is information on a form, then make this form_stat referring to a form only.

Comment: I thought one answer belongs to one form. Why would you delete this relationship, if that is the case? Doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: Sorry, I've update the rules and the diagram to be less confuse. I want to store the info for a response, and this info include the relation Response-Anwer, so one response is represented by the info of the respondent and the answer of the respondent for the questions.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer. One response table, one table liking the response to its answers.

Comment: Thanks for all @ThorstenKettner. So, do you think it is not a circular relationship with problems of consistency?

Comment: No, I see nothing circular about this.